# An attempt was made to retrieve an initial context for [ClassName] but no JNDI feature is configured

Tags: websphere, jndi, websphere-liberty

I am using the IBM WebSphere Application server v8.5 Liberty Profile. I have enabled the feature jndi-1.0 in server.xml by adding

```
<feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
```

But still I get the error "An attempt was made to retrieve an initial context for [ClassName] but no JNDI feature is configured."

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you specified any other JNDI-related or low-level options in jvm.options?

Comment: @bkail: I don't think so.

Comment: Then it could be a product issue. I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.